# How to convert the protobuf from xml using python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

i want to convert the protobuf object from given xml using python
my code was given below,

```
message =check_pb2.Tag()
dumped_json =json.dumps({"id":"01","name":"ranjith"})
loaded_json=json.loads(dumped_json)
print('loaded_json',loaded_json)
protocolBufferMessage = 
google.protobuf.json_format.Parse(loaded_json,message, 
ignore_unknown_fields=False)
print('protocolBufferMessage:',protocolBufferMessage)
```

I  got some error like this ,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xml_to_json.py", line 32, in <module>
objectJSONEncoder.xml_to_json('self', obj)
File "xml_to_json.py", line 24, in xml_to_json
protocolBufferMessage = 
google.protobuf.json_format.Parse(loaded_json,message, 
ignore_unknown_fields=False)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\google\protobuf\json_format.py", line 378, in Parse
if not isinstance(text, six.text_type): text = text.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Please give any suggestions?